# issues accessing an array in an object jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I am trying to access some data from an object as follows:

```
var summaryChanges = {
        dataToAdd:[
            {name:[]},
            {events:[]},
            {emails:[]}
        ],
        dataToRemove:[
            {name:[]},
            {events:[]},
            {emails:[]}
            ]
  }
```

i am trying to log the contents of the name property of data to add as follows:

```
console.log($(summaryChanges.dataToAdd.name)[0]);
```

however the console only logs undefined.

Comment: is that a valid object?

Comment: DataToAdd is an array, so you should access it as such. You can use `dataToAdd[0]` to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataToAdd` is an arrary not an object , so access it like

```
console.log(summaryChanges.dataToAdd[0].name[0])
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, still getting used to syntax of objects etc, much appreciated

Comment: how would I format the object so as to be able to access checkpoints as a key (I read that js doesn't do associative arrays) ie summaryChanges.dataToAdd.name[i]

Comment: Figured it out,:
var summaryChanges = {
    dataToAdd:{
        checkpoints:[],
 events:[],
 emails:[]
    },
    dataToRemove:{
 checkpoints:[],
 events:[],
 emails:[]
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize some things

1. `$(summaryChanges.dataToAdd.name)` you are creating a jQuery Object.
2. `summaryChanges` it's an object so you can do `sumaryChanges.dataToAdd`
3. `dataToAdd` it's an array, so for get a value you access it like this `dataToAdd[index]`

At the end you access it like this

`console.log(summaryChanges.dataToAdd[index].name[index])`